# jquery passage of comma-separated values

Tags: jquery

This is one of these very basic questions which is hard because i don't always know the terms.

So, if you use the right terms, it will help me ask more effectively in the future.

I understand the following:

```
var n='#mydiv';
$(n).html() //just an example
```

or this

```
$('.titles').click(function(){ /* another example */ });
```

BUT, the comma in this coding which I got off the web is throwing me off, I didn't know you could pass multiple items in the parentheses and I don't understand the significance of the second parameter.

```
$(el.fisheyeCfg.itemsText,this).get(0).style.display='block';
```

the source of this is here, (but I'm still where I need to understand the terminology and the syntax):
http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/358_jquery/example%20files/all-examples.html

Comment: Context http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: Fabricio, thank you, that was just the ticket!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM element after the comma is a context:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Basically, $(selector,context) would find all elements matching selector (e.g. '#mydiv') that are contained within (i.e. child nodes of) the DOM element assigned to context.

By default, the context of a query is the whole DOM.

Oh, and the context can be a jquery object, or a DOM element object.

So, for example:

```
var someElement = $('#aDiv'),
    paragraphs = $('p',someElement);
```

would mean that paragraphs points to all the paragraph tags within #aDiv.

Comment: BYossarian, thank you, as a starting guy I wouldn't have known to search for "context" so thanks.